# Limit number of retries Cucumber does

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm using cucumber-jvm in a java project and would like to configure it to not do any reruns if a test fails, default is that it tries 3 times.
I have searched "everywhere" but filed to find how to to that (thought it should be easy). Is it so that there is no way to do that?

Comment: Cucumber JVM doesn't rerun anything on it's own. You may want to look at your own systems.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean?

Comment: You're thinking that Cucumber retries failed scenarios 3 times by default. Cucumber doesn't do that. So either you may not be using Cucumber and need to look at the documentation of what you are actually using, or something else is using Cucumber to retry failures. Or there is something else that only you can know or learn about.

Comment: Ok, then I have been looking at the wrong place (when searched on google I really got the understanding that the retries were implemented directly in Cucumber). And since I don't implement it explicitly myself, I guess it is either in Spring or JUnit I should look further. Thank you!